# How do I get a Brother DCP-145C Printer working?

Tags: 12.10, printing, brother

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot get a Brother DCP-145C printer to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163500/cannot-get-a-brother-dcp-145c-printer-to-work)

Ubuntu 12.10 is refusing to acknowledge printer or the old drivers from brother. Been having this problem for the last few upgrades. Can't afford to keep upgrading devices.

Comment: Hi, is there a fix yet to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check post #5 here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+question/190331

Good luck!

Comment: ^ Hi & thank you, but that hasn't worked since 11.10. That driver is no good for 12.04 or 12.10.

Comment: Thank you chili555 for this now seems to have fixed part of the problem. It now prints, but still no scan. I can live with that for now.

Cheers